# WebServerException : Unable to start embedded Tomcat | Spring Boot Eureka Server

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

While learning spring MVC building with spring, I tried making a Eureka client and server using a tutorial, its a simple tutorial with a client and server main classes with just annotations and adding application properties. But even after following the tutorial the application wont run the tomcat. I can still run other projects i done in spring boot with tomcat at local server.
The tutorial i followed is,
https://dzone.com/articles/microservice-spring-cloud-eureka-server-configurat

---

```
2018-08-06 18:18:33.710  INFO 17919 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2018-08-06 18:18:33.810  INFO 17919 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
2018-08-06 18:18:33.810  WARN 17919 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/tuto-server/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-08-06 18:18:33.811  INFO 17919 --- [           main] c.t.eurekatuto.EurekaTutoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-06 18:18:33.819  INFO 17919 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@15515c51: startup date [Mon Aug 06 18:18:33 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@34f7234e
2018-08-06 18:18:34.426  INFO 17919 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=a5669830-fb3a-3b16-b157-1f80a6f9cbf9
2018-08-06 18:18:34.439  INFO 17919 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-08-06 18:18:34.488  INFO 17919 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$39babf2e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-06 18:18:34.681  INFO 17919 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-08-06 18:18:34.695  INFO 17919 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-08-06 18:18:34.695  INFO 17919 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2018-08-06 18:18:34.698  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-08-06 18:18:34.759  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-06 18:18:34.760  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 941 ms
2018-08-06 18:18:34.846  WARN 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-08-06 18:18:34.846  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-08-06 18:18:34.851  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@7c8e8b8f
2018-08-06 18:18:35.812  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.812  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.812  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.812  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.812  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.812  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.812  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'servletContainer' to urls: [/eureka/*]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.812  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.847  INFO 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
2018-08-06 18:18:35.879 ERROR 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [servletContainer]

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1114) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getClass(ReflectionHelper.java:629) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getClass(ReflectionHelper.java:625) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.getParameterizedType(ContextResolverFactory.java:202) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.init(ContextResolverFactory.java:89) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1332) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4637) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5282) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
    ... 36 common frames omitted

2018-08-06 18:18:35.880 ERROR 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2018-08-06 18:18:35.880 ERROR 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2018-08-06 18:18:35.883  WARN 17919 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [spring.cloud.inetutils] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2075)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
2018-08-06 18:18:35.887 ERROR 17919 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.techgentsia.eurekatuto.EurekaTutoApplication.main(EurekaTutoApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2018-08-06 18:18:35.888  INFO 17919 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-08-06 18:18:35.889  WARN 17919 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-08-06 18:18:35.896  INFO 17919 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-06 18:18:35.900 ERROR 17919 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.techgentsia.eurekatuto.EurekaTutoApplication.main(EurekaTutoApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:172) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:110) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please refer to [ask]. You haven't provided any information with which we can solve your problem. I recommend providing information about your setup, as well as any code and resources necessary for a [mcve].

Comment: @AndrewFan the setup is very simple, u can find how i did that in the link i have given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try add his dependency to your pom/gradle:

Pom >>

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-b180725.0427</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle >>

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180725.0427'
```

Ok, so what happened is, Java used bundle up that dependency in the older Java versions (<=8). But now they no longer bundle it from the latest version (JDK >=9) of Java going forward. I hope that solves your problem.
[Checkout this solution](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-jaxbexception) & [this one as well](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0)

Comment: The Error was in the the application properties, where i define the driver for my dataBase, after defining it properly it is solved. the jaxb-api was necessary, tnx for pointing it out @S34N.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solved it. & You're welcome. :-) @STAIN Thank you for posting up that question. It's going to help more people out there struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks that helped me.

Comment: Read this also: https://crunchify.com/java-11-and-javax-xml-bind-jaxbcontext/. Explains for other JDK versions and JAXB  support Java EE.